# How to update all object children fields based on parent rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Coupon which can be parent and child. User has only access to the parent coupon, and when he edits it, I need to update all of the children of it.
Update method looks like this right now:

```
def update
  add_breadcrumb edit_resource
  Coupon::Save.call(coupon: coupon)
  respond_with coupon, location: admin_coupon_path(coupon)
end
```

**Coupon::Save** is interactor there just for saving it. I guess I need to call after this interactor `previous_changes` method which gives me fields which were  updated. Then do something like coupon.children.update_all(coupon.previous_changes). How should I solve my problem?

Comment: Damir, I dont understand something, a coupon can has many coupons?
An User has one coupon, and the Coupon has many coupons? Maybe if you add more info of the User and Coupon association or the models it will be more easy to understand

Comment: User can create collection of coupons(with 1 parent) or just a single coupon.

Comment: What do you mean by `1 parent`?

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano user on the creating coupon page can choose what do he wants - single coupon for everyone(with redemption limin) or collection of uniq coupons which can be used only 1 time. So if it a collection of coupons - I set the first coupon as parent, and other will be children. Already creating/destroying works good, only edit left.

Comment: For example - admin creating a collection coupon - set the quantity for 2000, and press create  - I set first coupon of this 2000 as parent, and set the parent_id for all other 1999 coupons of this coupon.id. (First parent coupon parent_id will be nil, so next time i'll find the collection of the coupons by this parent)

Comment: Can you edit the question and add how you represent that association?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151064/discussion-between-matayoshimariano-and-damir-nurgaliev).